# How is the "Memory usage" value computed that is shown when I login to Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu, memory

When I login to my Ubuntu 11.10 box, several values are displayed by default. For example:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-17-virtual x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Thu Apr  5 20:35:07 UTC 2012

  System load:  0.01              Processes:           56
  Usage of /:   15.5% of 7.87GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 26%               IP address for eth0: XX.XXX.XX.XXX
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/
Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest
  http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud
```

I would like to know how the "Memory usage" value is calculated, so I can write a shell script to collect this and graph it over time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you login motd runs all of the files in `/etc/update-motd.d`. The output you're looking for comes from `50-landscape-sysinfo` which is a symlink to `/usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper`.

This is just a short script though:

```
#!/bin/sh
cores=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null)
[ "$cores" -eq "0" ] && cores=1
threshold="${cores:-1}.0"
if [ $(echo "`cut -f1 -d ' ' /proc/loadavg` < $threshold" | bc) -eq 1 ]; then
    echo
    echo -n "  System information as of "
    /bin/date
    echo
    /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo
else
    echo
    echo " System information disabled due to load higher than $threshold"
fi
```

Which indicates it comes from `landscape-sysinfo`. That output is just STDOUT for that utility. [Landscape](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/landscape) is all part of a Canonical system monitoring service. Find more information here:

- http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/landscape

If this isn't good enough Nagious is a more advanced but free networking monitoring tool that can monitor any number of machines. Cacti is a graphing web-frontend to RRDtool which is individual monitoring for a system.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! All my boxes run on Amazon and for the sake of simplicity, I have all my monitoring going through CloudWatch. So I really just want to parse and push this info into that. landscape-sysinfo is what I needed.